# Capture the Keywords from the search field in the form in Webflow?

Tags: forms, webflow, search-keywords

I have a search field in the header bar and want to capture Keywords what people are trying to find. I want to get and save the keywords in Webflow form back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This product might achieve what you need. They claim you can install within 30 seconds if you use Webflow. It doesn't store into Webflow CMS backend but at least you can use it for form tracking and analytics.

I use it for our site in a search box that does not have a submit button and it works great. The benefit for using FormTrackers is you don't need to write your own JS snippet.

- [formtrackers.com](https://formtrackers.com)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33929895)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can try to automate the process by utilizing Zapier, Make (ex. Integromat), or n8n (my choice) — search bar is a form field, so if you want to learn how to capture data from search bar, then you need to find out how to get data from form submissions.

A few guides:

- https://nocodequest.com/simple-webflow-form-submits-with-integromat/
- https://docs.n8n.io/nodes/n8n-nodes-base.webflowtrigger/ (this is n8n docs, I use it)

P.S: As I’ve mentioned before, I didn’t attempt to get data from a search bar, but I think this should work.